# Why I get TLSv1 issue on Spring boot and how to fix it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tls1.2

I am migrating a old application with plain Spring to Spring boot. After migrating the application I see this error:

```
2020-08-06 20:02:03.933  WARN 9986 --- [onnection adder] c.m.s.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel         : TLSv1 was negotiated. Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2 at minimum.
```

What is this and why I get this? Its first time I see this kind of message. I would be greatful if someone could explain me what this is and how I can fix this problem? Anything i can put to my `application.properties`? If yes, why? I want to understand :)

Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS is transport layer security (HTTPS & SSL). TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 are considered vulnerable. TLSv1.2 is the minimum you should run. Since that's coming from jdbc, that's one of your database connections. Whatever database that is, you need to configure the TLS to be v1.2 at a minimum. You shouldn't need to change anything on your app.